# How to set an object property as protected after injecting a config file in the constructor

Tags: php, oop

I have created a config file containing username and password to connect to my database.

I am passing this config file in the constructor of the class DatabaseService this way:

```
function __construct(){

   require __DIR__ .'../../../../config/db.config.php';

   $this->username = $db_config['username'];
}
```

Is there a way to set the username as protected once it has been created in the constructor? (keeping in mind the property value is based on a variable set in an external file)

Thank you

Comment: before function __construct set protected username; ?

Comment: of course, my bad I was only thinking of doing protected username = $config[..] which would inevitably fail. Thank you.

Comment: no problem, sometimes it only needs a fresh look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
protected username;

function __construct(){
   require __DIR__ .'../../../../config/db.config.php';

   $this->username = $db_config['username'];
}
```